# Is it possible to upload to youtube with the Zend library, but delay listing it until the time I specify?

Tags: zend-framework, youtube, youtube-api

I would like to be able to upload videos to youtube with the Zend library, but I would like the video to be hidden from everyone (such is being unlisted), and have the video be shown at the time I give.

So for example, I would upload a video on June 26th, but I would like it to stay unlisted until 3:00 PM June 27th.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible to upload the video as private or unlisted by setting the options on the VideoEntry object before you send it to the YouTube servers.  If you're using the Zend framework, you would do so like this:

```
// Set private
$videoEntry->setVideoPrivate();

// Or, set unlisted
$unlisted = new Zend_Gdata_App_Extension_Element( 'yt:accessControl', 'yt',
                                'http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007', '' );
$unlisted->setExtensionAttributes(array(
    array('namespaceUri' => '', 'name' => 'action', 'value' => 'list'),
    array('namespaceUri' => '', 'name' => 'permission', 'value' => 'denied')
));
$videoEntry->setExtensionElements(array($unlisted));
```

While it's not possible to have YouTube make the video available at a certain date/time, you can update the settings yourself (using cron or similar to fire it at the correct time)  like so:

```
// get update-able VideoEntry
$videoEntry = $yt->getFullVideoEntry( 'videoID' );

// Set public
$videoEntry->setVideoPublic();

// Set listed
$listed = new Zend_Gdata_App_Extension_Element( 'yt:accessControl', 'yt',
                                'http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007', '' );
$listed->setExtensionAttributes(array(
    array('namespaceUri' => '', 'name' => 'action', 'value' => 'list'),
    array('namespaceUri' => '', 'name' => 'permission', 'value' => 'allowed')
));
$videoEntry->setExtensionElements(array($unlisted));

// Send update
$putUrl = $videoEntry->getEditLink()->getHref();
$yt->updateEntry($videoEntry, $putUrl);
```